# Is there any open source project in c# or python to plot a Gantt chart?

Tags: c#, python, linux, plot, wxpython

I would like to plot an operating system log contains:

```
time-stamp   event
```

Events can be `tid` or `enter_irq#_handler` or `exit_irq#_handler` and each has its own unique identifier.

Does any one have a recommendation for a `c#` or `wxpython` I can use to build my own tool?

I have `100K` events and about `2k` unique events list of tid, irq etc.

I found [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/27/wxpython-pyplot-graphs-with-python/) and [that](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/LogOn.aspx?rp=/articles/32836/a-simple-c-library-for-graph-plotting), but they are not designed for `2k` unique events identifier.

I thought that Gantt chart is the right solution:

[image]

Comment: Provided your screen would be 2000 pixels high, what would a 2000 lines plot look like, you think?  Either I don't understand, or your request doesn't make sense.  Could you give an idea of what your plot should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write some GNU [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script feeding a [GnuPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) script.

You certainly want to collapse (= group), or select a tiny subset of, some event kinds together (and you should know which ones). Showing 2000 loosely related curves to a user has no sense, even on a gigantic high-resolution screen set.

<sup>Because human brains and eyes cannot grasp thousands of different curves at once</sup>